# Running batch file in ssis SQl Agent job

Tags: sql, sql-server

Scheduled a SSIS package on my Sql Server Agent, when i go to the Job History it says the Job succeded for the time it was scheduled to run, but im noticing the Job does nothing, i mean the Package is running but it's not doing what it is supossed to do.
I know the Package works because when i go to the BI Studio and rightclick>Execute Package it works.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a security issue. Agent jobs run as the Agent Service Account, so you want to make sure that account has correct permissions in the database or else you will need to create an SSIS proxy to run the job.